# How to parse this input in C

Tags: c

Right now i am doing an assignment but find it very hard to parse the user input in C. Here is kind of input user will input.

```
INSERT Alice, 25 Norway Drive, Fitzerald, GA, 40204, 6000.60
```

Here INSERT is the command (to enter in link list)
Alice is a name
25 Norway Drive is an address
Fitzerald is a city
GA is a state
40204 is a zip code
6000.60 is a balance

How can I use scanf or any other method in C to properly take this as input? The biggest problem in front of me is how to ignore these "," and store these values in separate variables of appropriate data types.

Thanks everyone, i have solve the issue and here is the solution:

```
   pch = strtok(NULL, ","); pch =
        substr(pch, 2, strlen(pch));  //substr is my custom funcition and i believe you can tell by its name what it is doing.
        strcpy(customer->streetAddress, pch);
```

Comment: It's called string tokenizing, and you can find a tutorial http://computerprogramming.suite101.com/article.cfm/string_tokenizing_in_c_programming

Comment: I have been doing this "tokenizing" but its not working for me because after "," there is a space so if i tokenize it " ," it make tokens after every space, which i dont want.

Comment: @itsaboutcode:  if you use strtok(3) with a comma delimiter, yes, you'll have to skip the leading whitespace in your resultant tokens.  Consult your system's documentation for isspace(3) try incrementing the pointer to your tokens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fast easy method:

Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to get the string from the user;
and [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to tokenize it.

*Edit*
After reading your comment:

Use `strtok()` with only the comma, and then remove trailing and leading spaces from the result.

*Edit2*
After a test run, I noticed you will get "INSERT Alice" as the first token. So, **after all tokens have been extracted**, run `strtok()` again, this time with a space, on the first token extracted. Or, find the space and *somehow* identify the command and the name from there.

Comment: Since you need to make a strtok() call for each token, just call it with space only for the first call, then switch to the comma for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If your input data format is fixed you can use something quick and dirty using [s]scanf().

With input of:

```
INSERT Alice, 25 Norway Drive, Fitzerald, GA, 40204, 6000.60
```

You might try, if reading from stdin:

```
char name[80], addr[80], city[80], state[80];
int zip;
double amt;

int res = scanf("INSERT %[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %d, %f\n",
    &name, &addr, &city, &state, &zip, &amt);
```

Should return the number of items matched (i.e. 6).

Comment: Is the %[^,] format standard? I don't think I've seen that before

Comment: The man page on my linux box says C89, C99, and POSIX.1-2001. I found it in the C89 Standard just now, so I assume it's been around a while. I did say it was quick and dirty ... worthy of a prototype, but ripe with possible problems, like the format of the input changing.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` may be a bit tricky in this situation, assuming that different commands with different parameters can be used.  I would probably use `fgets()` to read in the string first, followed by the use of `strtok()` to read the first token (the command).  At that point you can either continue to use `strtok()` with "," as the delimiter to read the rest of the tokens in the string, or you could use a `sscanf()` on the rest of the string (now that you know the format that the rest of the input will be in). `sscanf()` is still going to be a pain due to the fact that it appears that an unspecified number of spaces would be allowed in the address and possibly town fields.

Comment: @G. Noob:  if you really mean a strtok(3) delimiter of ", " (comma followed by space), that tokenizes too aggressively, as the OP already discovered and commented on.